# Why do I receive an error when I try to run node-sass as package.json script using npm?

Tags: npm, node-sass

I have this **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Landing page for natours",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
  },
  "author": "Robert",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I try to run **npm run compile:sass** it gives me this error:

[image: Error]

It worked for a while, but I updated the node version.

Also, if I run this command:

```
node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css
```

From the command line, it works.

- Node version: **14.17.0**
- npm version: **6.14.13**
- node-sass version: **6.0.0**

Comment: You don't have node-sass installed. Add it using `npm i node-sass` and then try to run the script again. Or make sure it is installed globally using `npm i -g node-sass`

Comment: The post was incomplete, sorry for that. Can you check it again please? Also I tried to install it globally with ```-g``` flag but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I uninstalled **node-sass** using this commands:

```
npm uninstall -S node-sass
npm uninstall -D node-sass
npm uninstall -g node-sass
```

And then install it again **globally**, using:

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

Before installing **globally**, I tried to install it with `-D` flag to add it to **dependencies** or `-S` flag to add it to **devDependencies** but it still didn't work, not sure why.

Maybe it's an incompatibility between **npm** and **node-sass** versions. I believe it can also be fixed using **nvm**.